# Shorter version for a series of list comprehension instructions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The following

```
ks = (5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15)

lo = list([(s**2-1) for s in ks[0:-1]])
lo.append(int((ks[-1]**2-1)*1.5))

inc = list([v/6 for v in lo[0:3]])
inc.extend([v/4 for v in lo[3:5]])
inc.append(lo[-1]/6)

mi = list([a + b for a, b in zip(lo, inc)])
hi = list([a + b for a, b in zip(mi, inc)])

CENTER_CELL = {'High': hi, 'Low': lo, 'Mid': mi}
```

results in

```
{'High': [32, 64, 106, 180, 252, 448],
 'Low': [24, 48, 80, 120, 168, 336],
 'Mid': [28, 56, 93, 150, 210, 392]}
```

Is there **any** way to compress the instructions above (except of typing, one-by-one, the 18 numbers)?

Comment: Rather than having us try and dig around to figure out the purpose of your code, can you show us mathematically what you are trying to do?

Comment: If anything, I would suggest you write a **longer** version - what is `ks`? `s`? I guess `lo`, `mi`, `hi` are low, middle and high but `inc`?

Comment: It has to do with High Pass (Filter) Kernel(s). `ks` stands for kernel size(s). For each kernel of size n*n, a center cell value (for the kernel itself) is derived as a function of the kernel's size. The conventional formula for the center cell value is n*2-1. See http://asprs.org/a/publications/pers/2008journal/september/abstracts.html#p1107. In this publication, the center cell values aren't exactly following the formula. Maybe some of them are empirical -- I couldn't find a unique sequence pattern. Out of pure interest to learn and practice Python, I am trying to compress further the code.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong in posting this here. I am asking for ways to make the code shorter. For example, can the two last lines be combined in one?

Comment: If your code does what you want it to (i.e. it works), and you're just looking for ways to make it better, you might be interested in [`codereview`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  But be warned: they'll help you to make code *better*, which is not the same thing as making it *shorter*.

Comment: @DSM I didn't know about codereview. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `numpy`, which makes these vector operations easier:

```
import numpy as np

ks = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15])
lo = np.int64((ks**2 - 1)*np.array([1]*5 + [1.5]))
inc = np.int64(lo*np.array([1/6.]*3 + [1/4.]*2 + [1/6.]))
CENTER_CELL = {'High': lo + 2*inc, 'Low': lo, 'Mid': lo + inc}
```

But honestly, I don't quite understand why you want to compress your code. I agree with jonrsharpe, you could indeed also make it longer.